# Line break after <td>?

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, formatting, html-table

I want to achieve this formatting in vs2010 inside table tag:

```
<tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="first_name" runat="server" /></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="last_name" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
```

But VS 2010 does this :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="first_name" runat="server" /></td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="last_name" runat="server" /></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Pecific Options :
Default Setting > Client tag
& Default Setting > Client HTML Tags td
LineBreaks: None, Before & After, After etc... no option gives me what im after!

Before & After preview looks like what I want but it doesn't work when I hit ctrl+k+d!

If it turns out VS2010 wont do it, does anyone know of a tool that will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track with the method you were trying. However you also need to set the Line breaks for the asp:Textbox tag as well that is under Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Pecific Options > ASP.NET controls. If you see asp:Textbox it probably has Line Breaks set to before and after as well.

Comment: Brilliant! some days I just cant see the wood for the trees...I changed Default Settings > Server tag... LineBreaks:None to cover all server tags, thanks vmex151

Comment: Not a problem. If this fixed your issue could you accept it as an answer to give me some rep points